# Spring Security SSO / Font Awesome primefaces not loading

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces, fonts, font-awesome

I have programmed SSO with Kerberos / Spring Security. SSO is working like a charm, however there is one issue. Primeface's font awesome isn't loaded and following exception is printed on screen:

> ERROR o.a.m.a.ResourceHandlerImpl - Error trying to load resource
>   fa/fontawesome-webfont.eot with library primefaces :java.io.exception:
>   an existing connection has been terminated under software control by
>   the host computer

In web.xml I've added

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Why is primefaces not loading font awesome after single sign on? How can I load the icons? Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try with your antivirus off? It looks like the error says something external terminated a connection. I'm just taking a wild guess here.

Comment: that doesn't seem to work out. Any other idea?

Comment: I'm not sure I can help on this one I'm not experienced enough. However the error says a connection has been terminated by the host computer. So something is disconnecting font awesome for some reason I guess. Other parts of primefaces are working as intended right ? You should post the whole stacktrace of the error I think it's gonna be easier to spot the problem. Also what server are you using ? It's relevant to the problem.

Comment: well you could load font awesome externally by adding the css file and not via primefaces but it's not really fixing your issue.

Comment: I will try your suggestion, thanks for your support!